# Copying Database in document directory is having issues

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a app in which I need to copy my database file to document directory. I know how to do that and it is working good. Here is the code for it

```
// Get Required Path
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];

// Check if DB file already Exist. If YES than return. 
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success) return success;

// If DB file is not exist try to write file. This will execute first time only.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
// Add Skip Backup attribute here.
```

This works fine but due to some reason sometimes it generates error. Now the problem is When I try to trace this problem it doesn't occur.

I don't know why but `success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];` is returning NO. Than it attempt to write new file but writing new file gets fail also. Its very hard to trace the `error` as it is not reproducing in my testing.

Can anyboday tell me the possible errors due to this happening and provide solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error occuring ?

Comment: That is not I am getting as It occurred in one device only and that device is not with me. Not occurring in my device.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Following code

```
BOOL copySucceeded = NO;


   // Get our document path.
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Get the full path to our file.


    NSString *filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



    // Get a file manager
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Does the database already exist? (If not, copy it from our bundle)
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

        // Get the bundle location
        NSString *bundleDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];

        // Copy the DB to our document directory.
        copySucceeded = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundleDBPath
                                             toPath:filePath
                                              error:nil];

        if(!copySucceeded) {
           //not Copy
        }
        else {
          // Success
        }

    }
    else {
       // Nothing
    }
```